# Gcc compilation for different targets

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, instruction-set

I was just trying to understand something about cross compilers which made me ask this question.
`gcc` is a cross-compiler.
By default what it the target architecture for `gcc` compilation if none is specified is the native target on which I am compiling the source. Correct ?

If the above is correct then how does it manage to generate the code for several different architectures even when it is explicitly specified ?
Shouldn't it have to know all the ISA's ? How is this managed ? Do they have all the information for all the existing ISA's ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A given (particular) `gcc` is built for a particular given target. Use `gcc -v` to find out which.

Often, cross-compilers are installed as different commands, e.g. `avr-gcc` on Debian for the [Atmel AVR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR) processor (with specific [options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Options.html) ...)

On some architectures and systems (typically x86 & Linux) you may compile for a different variant. See [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html). In particular you may want to use `-mtune=native` or `-march=haswell` or `-m32` ...

If you build `gcc` yourself from its [source tarball](http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html), you'll give it at configure time specific [configure options](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) (e.g. `--program-suffix=-avr` and `--target=avr` for the `avr-gcc` etc....)

Comment: You mean this comes from `installing` different kinds of `gcc`s ?

Comment: Yes, as I am explaining in my revised answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. And the link is nice. I will refer to the gnu docs from now on an understand.